# Inserting posts into a UICollectionView grid?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, firebase-realtime-database

Need some guidance on how to approach this. I'm not sure if I'm completely over complicating it or if it is a mess.

I've got a UICollectionView that I want to always have 9 cells and I'm wanting users to be able to insert posts by tapping on a cell..so if they press on cell 8, they make their post, and it shows up there in the 8th cell with potentially 8 other empty cells around it.

I'm posting/pulling these posts from firebase...so I was thinking the flow needed to look something like:

1) Make an empty array of 9 empty [Posts] so that the cells appear and are clickable.

2) On the firebase observer .. if there are say 3 posts able to be returned, it inserts them into the post array / replaces 3 empty posts.

3) I want the posts to show up sort of randomly throughout the grid, so I figured I'd shuffle the array before reloading the data?

4) I don't really care if the posts back from firebase are in the same spot as they were placed by the user, but I want when a user puts a post for it to stay in the same spot as they placed it, so I figured I'd save a variable to firebase like "position : 8" and I'd say something like "If your user uid = the uid of the post, grab the position number and insert that post at that index of the array.

Is this flow way off base or is there a better way to accomplish this? I haven't seen much about inserting items into certain positions into a table view/collection view.

Edit:

```
func fillWithBlanks() {
        for i in 0  ..< 9 {

            let blankPost = Post(timestamp: 99999999999999999, picURL: nil, postKey: "") // 100% need a better timestamp there, just filler for now.

            postsArray.append(blankPost)

        }
    }
```

and then

```
DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.queryOrderedByChild("timestamp").queryStartingAtValue(cutoff).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


    let time = snapshot.value!["timestamp"] as? Int
    let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as? String
    let picURL = snapshot.value!["imageURL"] as? String
    let key = snapshot.key

    let post = Post(timestamp: time!, picURL: picURL!, postKey: key)

    self.postsArray[self.selectedPostIndex] = post

    self.collectionView.reloadData()

})
```

So basically on viewDidLoad I'm calling fillWithBlanks(), and then when I select a cell I set the selectedPostIndex to the index clicked on, create a post, and insert it in where I selected.

This works and I tested it by printing out the cell's timestamp when I press on it, and sure enough when I make a post the timestamp is appropraite to the post and not the 99999999.

My massive issue I'm having are the pictures. When I load up I get 9 cells that are empty but when I make a post it sets the picture I set for the post to all 9 cells, and then if I make 2 posts, I get a very Simon-says'ie flashing in all of my cells between the first picture, second picture, and the blank background from the blank cell.

When I make a post I'm saving a download url to firebase and then I have a caching system that downloads the posts or grabs them in. It all worked before trying to implement the blank posts.

Any ideas what would be causing that? I don't understand why appending a new post would do anything to the blank posts I'm making when the app loads up. I'm assuming I'm having some misunderstanding with classes and my Post array/ Post objects aren't what they need to be.

---

Edit 2:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let post = postsArray[indexPath.row]

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MainCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PostCell

    if let imageURL = post.picURL {

        cell.cellImage.loadImageUsingNSCache(imageURL)


    }

    return cell

}
```

and the .loadimagesUsingNSCache comes from :

```
extension UIImageView {

func loadImageUsingNSCache(urlString: String){


    if let cachedImage = imageCache.objectForKey(urlString) as? UIImage {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString)


                    self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }





            })


        }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: It sounds nice, now you should try and write the code and update your question with the results you've got. In that way others can help you if you have any specific problems.

Comment: Alright, I just was a bit weary to start writing code in case I was WAY off base or something. Gonna go try to cook up something now, thanks for the input :)

Comment: Never cut your own wings :)

Comment: @VladimirNul Added some code. Having some pretty massive issues with pictures but the basic logic is working otherwise. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean ideas for the pictures? What problems are you facing?

Comment: This might warrant an entirely different question but I talk about it in my edit a bit.

When I'm making a post the picture I pass in to download from a url gets applied to all 9 posts and not just that one. My posting/images were working before I added in the blank posts, so I'm not sure why these blank posts should be taking on anything from the new posts. Surely they're just totally separate.

Comment: Can you provide collectionView(cellForItemAtIndexPath) method?

Comment: @VladimirNul Thanks for your time with this, I appreciate it.

I added another edit. It's under Edit 2

It might actually be my cache now that I think of it. This is my first time using a cache so that might be all whack.

Comment: Remember collection view cells are reusable items, so you need to tell what's the content of every item inside every time you call `collectionView(cellForItemAtIndexPath)`. That means you need to provide a value for `cell.cellImage` every time, even if `post.picURL` is `nil`. In that case you can say `cell.cellImage = nil` or show a default empty picture.

Comment: @VladimirNul Thank you so much for your time/patience. That's exactly what I needed to do. Still a little buggy but I'm gonna just work on it tomorrow and if need be post a separate question.

Setting cell.cellimage to nil was exactly what I needed to do to solve that issue though. 

Appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the problem with the images, remember collection view cells are reusable items, so you need to tell what's the content of every item inside every time you call `collectionView(cellForItemAtIndexPath)`.

That means you need to provide a value for `cell.cellImage` every time, even if `post.picURL` is `nil`. In that case you can say `cell.cellImage = nil` or show a default empty picture.